# Metamask Transaction pending of bscscan

Tags: bsc, gas-limit, bscscan

my transaction of bscscan mainnet metamask showing pending on metamask but when i increase the gas fee it gets executed , what might be the issue , is it contract optimization issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It is basically the nature of blockchain network.

When a user executes a transaction, such as on the Ethereum network, they are required to include a gas fee, paid in ETH, as an incentive for validators to process their transaction. The value of the gas fee is determined by the network traffic and the user's preference for transaction speed.

Consequently, during periods of high network traffic, a transaction may experience delays (typically 2-3 blocks) when utilizing the minimum gas fee. Fortunately, Metamask provides a solution to expedite a pending transaction that is taking too long to confirm by increasing the gas fee and prioritizing its processing, named as "Speed up".

This mechanism involves replacing the original transaction with a new one, featuring a higher gas fee, thereby enhancing the likelihood of swift processing by the network.

Hope it helps you.